# hibernate Group By clause return NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I try to use group by clause in hibernate using criteria
but when I use ResultTransformer it getting error NullPointerException
here is my code :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<ModelNilai> getListNilaiAwal(Integer page, Integer id, Integer idm) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            List<ModelNilai> list = new ArrayList<ModelNilai>();

            Criteria c = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ModelNilai.class);
            c.createAlias("mahasiswa","mh");
            c.add(Restrictions.eq("mh.id", id));
            c.createAlias("makul","m");

            c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.groupProperty("m.id"), "id"));

            c.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ModelNilai.class));




            list.addAll(c.list());
            System.out.println("size"+list.size());

            if(page==null){
                setTotalPage(c);
            }



return list;
}
```

This is the query result:

```
Hibernate: select m2_.id_makul as y0_ from tbl_nilai this_ inner join tbl_mhs mh1_ on this_.id_mhs=mh1_.id_mahasiswa inner join tbl_makul m2_ on this_.id_makul=m2_.id_makul where mh1_.id_mahasiswa=? group by m2_.id_makul
```

I think my query is right, because when i try to see the list.size() , it give me the right size,,
But still getting NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
id.ac.undip.mlearning.controller.NilaiController.listNilaiAwal(NilaiController.java:60)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

This is ModelNilai.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_nilai")
public class ModelNilai {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type="java.lang.Integer")
    @Column(name="id_nilai")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nilai")
    private int nilai;
        @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_makul")
    private ModelMakul makul;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_kuis")
    private ModelKuis kuis;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_mhs")
    private ModelMahasiswa mahasiswa;
```

This is ModelMahasiswa.java

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="tbl_mhs")
public class ModelMahasiswa {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type="java.lang.Integer")
    @Column(name="id_mahasiswa")
    private Integer id;

    @Column (name="NIM")
    private String NIM;

    @Column (name="Nama")
    private String nama;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_jurusan")
    private ModelJurusan jurusan;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mahasiswa",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<ModelNilai> nilai;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(name="tbl_makul_diambil", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_mahasiswa")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_makul")})
    private Set<ModelMakul> makul;
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: Which line of the method cause NPE?

Comment: I dont know, but when I add c.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ModelNilai.class)); it cause NPE, 
but when I remove it, will cause Class Cast Exception

Comment: Again, when do you get NPE? When you call `list.addAll(c.list());`?

Comment: Can you share the class ModelNilai? Probably, one of the columns returned is null and the field that it is used to set is a primitive type.

Comment: Ok,,,I add ModelNilai and ModelMahasiswa class